# Accessing list from Site collection A inside SitcollectionB

Tags: list, sharepoint-enterprise, site-collection

I have two site collections (A and B) belonging to the same content database. Inside site collection A there is a list "List1".. now i want to have the same list in the site collection B such -  if there are any changes made to the list 1 in site collection A the same changes should b reflected in  list1 inside site collection B - is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it many ways:

1. As Vardhaman suggested, use appropriate Item event handlers
2. Using Item Created, changed, Deleted workflows
3. Timer job which will periodically sync both lists.

Steps 2 & 3 will give control to users for manually syncying at anytime

Answer (score 1):

What kind of changes are we talking about?

If by changes you mean syncing of items, then you can simply write Item Receivers on List A for the `ItemAdded`, `ItemDeleted` and `ItemUpdated` events. When any of these events occur in List A, these receivers will open up SiteCollection B and inside that open up List B and do the necessary changes.

Here is a comprehensive guide on writing event receivers:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg749858.aspx